# SAS, Trailing with @

Tags: sas, format, dataset

I am trying to be able to format the start point of each observation where @2 would be the second character, (@3 the third etc) of each observation rather than from the beginning. For example this data set would be ONE WO REE R

```
data TEST; 
input @1 A $ @2 B $ @3 C $ @4 D $; 
cards;
ONE TWO THREE FOUR
;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
data TEST; 
input A $ +1 B $ +2 C $ +3 D $; 
cards;
ONE TWO THREE FOUR
;
RUN;
```

Comment: Didn't realise it was that easy, thanks! When would you use @ instead of +?

Comment: No problem. @n is an absolute pointer control and moves the pointer to column n. +n is a relative pointer control and moves the pointer n columns to the right. You can read about both here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en